# How to get index and delete a element from an object in angular 8?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular8

I am trying to delete an element from an object but it is not deleting from the object.

My Object is in the following format

{"UNDET":0,"HLDS":8,"NGS":2,"NGRT":1,"TotalCount":13,"NGX":1}

Now, I want to delete the key and value of an element(for ex: "NGRT":1) based on its index or key name,
I have tried splicing elements individually i.e keys and values separately but the problem here is after splicing elements the keys and values are getting misaligned

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you tried something? if you tried some code then we will help you find the errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to delete a key from an object, then use `delete` operator:

```js
const obj = {"UNDET":0,"HLDS":8,"NGS":2,"NGRT":1,"TotalCount":13,"NGX":1};

delete obj['NGRT'];

console.log(obj);
```

[As mdn says:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete)

> The JavaScript delete operator removes a property from an object; if
>   no more references to the same property are held, it is eventually
>   released automatically.

Comment: @Akki I am glad to help you!:)